# problems with R - ANDROID

Tags: java, android

when i create a layout called  " main.xml ":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

when i go to the main to create a button 
"  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); "
i have an error , i cant find the button in R.id 
and same for the spinner 
the id dont exist in R.id

help me plz

Comment: Post the code of your activity.

Comment: Have you tried a build-clean of your project?

Comment: You need to post the logcat/staketrace with your code so we can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably importing the wrong version of R.  There are two versions which exist: the static R class which exists in android.R and then there is also yourPackageName.R.  If you import the former none of your Ids will be found.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have any files, pictures, etc in your drawable or assets folder with capital letters, spaces, or dashes. Just use plane old lowercase. Also, try to clean your project. Go to project > clean. Then restart eclipse. Hope this helps. Also eclipse won't reconize any changes in XML files without saving first. Make sure to save after you add a button, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify that there is no errors in your XML files,than try to clean the project.